# What kind of word is "care about"?

Tags: verbs

would you mind helping me.?

What kind of word is "care about" in this sentence follwing?. Is it a phrasal verb or idiom?

**She cares deeply about environmental issues.**

Answer (score 1):

It's neither.  "**She cares**" is the root of the sentence. "Deeply" is merely an adverb describing how she cares.  "About environmental issues" is a prepositional phrase that likewise describes how she cares.  Here is a diagram of the sentence helping to expose those qualities

[image]

Comment: as your diagram, "care" is an intransitive verb? and "environmental issues" is not a object, it just a moifier?

Comment: **modifier**.  Correct on all points.

Comment: Thank RYA so much.
Can you make a diagram of this sentence "She cares more about his job". "more" is a pronoun or adverb?

Comment: @TinhVan that sentence diagram would look identical except with "more" instead of "deeply."  The word "more" in that case would be an adverb.

Comment: Just one more question. :)

"More" is a degree adverb and "deeply" is a manner adverb? They are both end position adverb. They must be at the end of sentence. But in this situation, we have "about environmental issues" and "about his job" are both adverb phrase. 

 So "more" and "deeply" precede adverb phrase because they are shorter. 

is that right?

Comment: @TinhVan there is no requirement regarding the order of the modifiers.  You could write "She cares about environmental issues deeply."  And it would mean the same thing.